# Why is "INSERT INTO SELECT" slower than just the inserts?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I have 100,000 rows in table1 and I want to create table2 with equal data (they both have the same structure) so I did

`INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1` and it took about 15 seconds.

If in php I do

```
while (SELECT * FROM table1){

    INSERT INTO table2...

}
```

this takes 10 seconds.  Why would insert into select be slower?

Comment: Did you run the check 1 time or multiple times? Is it average or `insert into select` always slower?

Comment: A MySQL `SELECT` query uses a considderable amount of resources compared to `INSERT`. In the first query, you execute 100.000 `SELECT` queries whereas inside PHP you only execute 1.

Comment: Run each test twice; let's see both timings.  Caching _may_ explain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a query containing "SELECT * FROM table1" then iterate over the result, you will only execute one query related to selecting data from table1.

However, if you do a "SELECT * FROM table1" inside the insert, I think it will insert and select for each row, resulting in 100 000 selects as well as 100 000 inserts instead of 1 select and 100 000 insert.

Not 100% sure, so someone please correct me if I am wrong and I'll remove this answer.